# Docker in PyCharm - Can I read files on my host computer?

Tags: docker, pycharm, docker-for-windows

I am on Windows, using docker in PyCharm to resolve dependency issues in my project. Since I am new to docker, I'm not sure if I'll still be able to read files that that are on my PC.

For example, `print(__file__)` results in `/opt/project/version-1.py` and im not sure where this is located. The files I would like to read reside in `C:\datasets\kitti\train\`

This is what I typed to run the docker image

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v C:/test:/root/shared floydhub/dl-docker:cpu bash
```

Ive been trying to look for the folder /root/shared but I cant find it. There is only root :( This is so stressful

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can mount one or more local directories inside your Docker container. This way you can give PyCharm access to your source files.

This is straightforward on Linux using the `-v <host-directory>:<container-path>` option.

On Windows it's a bit more complicated. See this tutorial: [docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories](https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c)

The gist of it is that you have to first share a drive in the settings of Docker and then you can mount it the same way as on Linux. For instance, if you have shared drive `D:`, you can mount directory `D:\data` on it like this:

```
D:\>docker run -v d:/data:/data alpine ls /data
```

This will start the `alpine` container and execute the `ls` command to show the content of the shared directory.

Comment: Hi I followed your advice but I still can't find the shared folder. I have edited my question above to include my last step.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the link I added? The main thing there is that you have to share your C: drive with Docker before your docker containers can access it. I don't have a Windows box - only Linux machines, so I can't try it myself.